# Validation of Class with FluentValidation returning object is required for non-static field

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to add FluentValidator to my .net core 3.1 Worker Service.  I created a class that will hold my CSV parsed files.

```
   public partial class Subjects
    {
        public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string LastNameInitial { get; set; }
        public string CodeDisplay { get; set; }
        public Guid? RaceId { get; set; }
        public Guid? MaritalStatusId { get; set; }
        public Guid? StatusId { get; set; }
        public string Rank { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public bool MobilePhoneDoNotLeaveMsg { get; set; }
        public bool MobilePhoneDoNotText { get; set; }
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
        public bool WorkPhoneDoNotLeaveMsg { get; set; }
    }
```

Then according to the documentation, I create the Validation class implementing the AbstractValidator interface:

```
class SubjectsValidation : AbstractValidator<Subjects>
{
    public SubjectsValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(subject => Subjects.FirstName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, I need to add the rules in the constructor.  However, when I pass in the lambda for the rule I got this error:

> "An object reference is required for non-static field, method, or
> property"

So I modified the constructor like this:

```
class SubjectsValidation : AbstractValidator<Subjects>
{
    public SubjectsValidation()
    {
        Subjects subject = new Subjects();
        RuleFor(x=>subject.FirstName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Which got of the error, but when I try to call the validation I get an error when I instantiate the object for testing:

```
Subjects subject = new Subjects();
            subject.FirstName = "John";
            SubjectsValidation validator = SubjectsValidation();
```

This returns a failed message because I had to create a new subject in the Subject Validation so it return a failure.  So following the instructions on the website, I just can't get this working.  How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to use the parameter provided in the expression: `subject => subject.FirstName`

Comment: Thank you that did it.  I was in the weeds and needed another set of eyes.  Thanks.  Add this as an answer and I'll mark it as such if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RuleFor` method is expecting a delegate. So your first attempt will work if you use the parameter of the delegate within the body (`subject` instead of `Subjects`):

```
class SubjectsValidation : AbstractValidator<Subjects> 
{ 
    public SubjectsValidation()
    { 
        RuleFor(subject => subject.FirstName).NotEmpty(); 
    } 
}
```